# How to add bracket in ToC after number

Tags: table-of-contents, brackets

1)  or like 1.1) or 1.1.1)

I want to have my table of content list with a bracket after the number. How can i do that?
Just started with my project, but want to figure it out now.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12]{report}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\input{tex/Einleitung}\newpage\cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A good answer depends on the classes you are using and if are already using a ToC package also on those packages. So we really need a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. Please add it to your question.

Comment: You example is not compilable, because it  depends on unknown files. Please have look at the links in my first comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: If you can switch to a KOMA-Script class then use the [answer of @Schweinebacke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/402883/43317).

With a standard class you can use package `tocloft` and redefine `\cftpartaftersnum`, `\cftchapaftersnum` etc.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\clist_map_inline:nn {chap,sec,subsec,subsubsec,para,subpara}
  {\cs_set_nopar:cpn {cft #1 aftersnum} ##1 {)}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this does not work for part entries in TOC. If `\part` is used then `\@part` must be patched:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@part
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart)\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
```

---

But it is also possible to use `tocbasic` with a standard class:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn {chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
  {\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\numberwithbracket]{tocline}{#1}}
\cs_set_nopar:Npn \numberwithbracket #1 {#1)\hfill}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The result is similar.

If there are parts, you could use the same patch for `\@part` as above or you could use

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@part
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}}
  {\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect\numberline{\thepart}#1}}
  {}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[numwidth=1.5em,dynnumwidth]{tocline}{part}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn {part,chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph}
  {\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[entrynumberformat=\numberwithbracket]{tocline}{#1}}
\cs_set_nopar:Npn \numberwithbracket #1 {#1)\hfill}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a KOMA-Script class like `scrartcl`, `scrbook` or `scrreprt`, this would be very easy:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\let\autodot)}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: Example using scrartcl]